# Custom Variable in Fastlane Script

Tags: ruby, fastlane

Sorry for such a newbie question, but I'm very confused on how to write a Fastlane script outside of using the supplied methods.

What I'm looking to do is create a variable called `message`, that can be passed to the `after_all` function, so when I post to Slack, each lane can have it's own custom message:

```
put message # is this how to set a variable?
lane :alpha do
    # This is what I'd like to do
    message = "[Google Play] Alpha Channel Deployed"
end

after_all |lane, options| do
    slack(message: message)
end
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm so utterly lost on how to create and pass variables that don't come from the command line in a Fastfile script

Comment: You set a variable using the `=` operator, just as you have on line 4. A local variable exists only within the scope where it's created. I don't know anything about Fastlane, but assuming the block passed to `lane` is called before block passed to `after_all`, then changing the first line to `message = nil` (so that the variable exists outside the first block's scope) might work.

Comment: And if you don't know how to use Ruby, a good start would be to read some docs beginning, perhaps, with [this tutorial](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/).

Comment: @Jordan - That worked. I guess I just needed to initialize it first. The tutorials I was reading last night didn't help on that front; I'll take a look at what you posted!

Comment: @Jordan - Could you post your comment as an answer so I can give you some sweet, sweet points?

Comment: Glad it worked! Posted an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You set a variable using the `=` operator, just as you have on line 4. A local variable exists only within the scope where it's created. Assuming the block passed to `lane` is called before block passed to `after_all`, then changing the first line to `message = nil` (so that the variable exists outside the first block's scope) ought to work:

```
message = nil

lane :alpha do
  message = "[Google Play] Alpha Channel Deployed"
end

after_all |lane, options| do
  slack(message: message)
end
```

Comment: I am trying to execute a shell script going one directory back. I also need to pass a param to this script dynamically like this, `lane :addPrivateKey do | options |
 sh ('cd .. &&  ./add_key.sh options[:clientKey]')
end`. Right now its taking options[:clientKey] as the param instead of the actual param sent to the lane. I know it is in string that's why but how to get it out from options variable?

Answer (score 19):

Alternatively you can also do the following:

```
lane :alpha do
  @message = "[Google Play] Alpha Channel Deployed"
end

after_all |lane, options| do
  slack(message: @message)
end
```

Comment: Works perfect, but whats going on there? Could you pls explain to not ruby guys.

Comment: Answer to myself, it is just ivar :)

Answer (score -1):

As of Fastlane 2.69 you can now create fastfile using swift!
ref: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.69.0